# Visual Studio 2010, any references made are created with an empty full path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, reference

I'm attempting to add a couple references to a VS 2010 project (the solution contains approximately 45 projects), and every time I add a reference from the list(
right-click project,properties>Framework and References>Add New Reference...), the full path is empty.

Link Library Dependency is set to true, and they all have names, labels and identities. the full path is just empty.

SOLVED, see below.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you create a new solution containing 2 new projects? i.e. can project 1 reference project 2?

Comment: Just figured it out, had to copy over some of the boost and other library directories in the linker from x64 to x86 and vice versa.